# Find the limit of right angles ( is it possible?)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Image updated

[image]

My question is it possible to find the limit of right angles which is what the question seem to be asking?

Comment: This picture is horrifying.

Comment: "The limit of right angles" doesn't really make sense.

Comment: What do you mean by "the limit of the right angles"? By the construction you've got going on, the "right angles" are constant: they are always a right angle. Should we be finding what a certain side-lenght is approaching? One of the other angles maybe? I can't immediately think of anything in the figure that isn't going to either $0$ or $\infty$.

Comment: @mapierce271: It looks to me as if the (non-right) angles $P_nAP_{n+1}$ might converge towards something like $\tan^{-1}(\sqrt 3)$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I think $P_nAP_{n+1}$ would converge to a right angle (since $P_nP_{n+1}$ and $AP_{n+1}$ are approaching infinity). It's not $0$ or $\infty$, but it isn't that interesting. [I am wrong here]

Comment: @mapierce271: Just because both of them go to infinity doesn't in itself say anything about whether their _ratio_ tend to a limit (and in that case what the limit is).

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Show that $\displaystyle |AP_n|^2 = \frac{4^{n-1}+2}3$.

Comment: Can I show by inputting the values 1,2... and confirm equality that way? By the way, why did you square the left side?

Comment: @user983246, have you learned how to prove equalities by mathematical induction?